# Get specific data from an external domain

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://www.color-hex.com/color-palette/35967

Using javascript/JQuery I want to get the colors from the above color palette website. The only api I found seemed limited.

Any answers for api's or other palette-picker sharing sites are accepted as well. API's are preferred.

Edit: 
found a promising api: http://www.colourlovers.com/api
Though being a bit of a noob means I do not know exactly how I'm supposed to use it without an explicit javascript example :'(

Comment: what have you tried so far? Are you loading it into your own page?

Comment: @Forty3 I'm just trying to get a point in the right direction since I can't really find many examples of this.

Comment: Just call the URL using ajax and specify JSON format returned. Lots of examples, just make sure it is JSONP `"http://www.colourlovers.com/api/color/35967" ` The JSON returned is right on that site. Will leave it to you to search that.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss thanks, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the structure of the page:

```
$("table.table tr td a").each((i,e) => console.log($(e).html()))
```

should output the list of five hex colors representing the palette. However, without knowing how you are using the information, obtaining the HTML from the page is still a mystery.

Have a look at examples using $.get() and $.parseHTML() in hopes of pulling the page's data and then manipulating the resultant DOM.

Comment: I'd like to try to find an official api if possible before doing it this way.